# Checkstyle Class implement error

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a class of a specific test type that extends an abstract test class named BasicTest. BasicTest has an abstract runTest() function that I expect each test to provide code for.

I have written the code for each runTest() and Checkystyle is complaining that "implements tests.BasicTest.runTest()."

Isn't that the point? What is the error here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesnt read like an error

Comment: I guess I should specify that I am using Eclipse and it is popping up as one of their alert triangles with an exclamation.

Comment: Did you use `@Override`?

Comment: Wow.... that did it. Sorry, I guess this stems from me misunderstanding override. I thought we only use override in Java when the code is different from that of the parent class. E.g. you don't want parent class code to run, but you want the subclass code to run.

Thanks for the easy solution